# Subtracting two Option[Double]

Tags: scala, scala-option

I have two variables that are optional double and I want to consider them as `0` when they are `None`

```
var x: Option[Double] = Option(0)
var y: Option[Double] = Option(0)
println("Expected 0 : "+(x ++ y).reduceOption(_ - _)) // 0

x = Option(4)
y = Option(0)
println("Expected 4 : "+(x ++ y).reduceOption(_ - _)) // 4

x = Option(0)
y = Option(4)
println("Expected -4 : "+(x ++ y).reduceOption(_ - _)) // -4

x = Option(4)
y = None
println("Expected 4 : "+(x ++ y).reduceOption(_ - _)) // 4

x = None
y = Option(4.0)
println("Expected -4 : "+(x ++ y).reduceOption(_ - _)) // 4
```

The last one I am expecting `-4` but I get `4`.

If I use

```
(for (i <- x; j <- y) yield i - j)
```

then I get `None`.

Also If I try

```
x.getOrElse(0) - y.getOrElse(0) // value - is not a member of AnyVal
```

then I get error `value - is not a member of AnyVal`

Comment: `None ++ Option(4.0)` evaluates to `Iterable(4.0)`. Since there is only one element in the collection there is nothing to reduce, so no subtraction takes place.

Comment: `0` is not a `Double`. For that you need `0.0` or `0D` or `0d`. Try that in your `getOrElse()` calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The `(x ++ y).reduceOption(_ - _)` is a perfect example of how to confuse people in Scala IMHO. It's not immediate that `++` operates on `Option` because they are also `Seq`.*

That being said, as already suggested in the comments, the straightforward way would be to use `getOrElse`:

```scala
x.getOrElse(0d) - y.getOrElse(0d)
```

You need to precise the `d` to have an `Double` otherwise, you get an `AnyVal` because `AnyVal` is the only common parent type of `Int` (from the `getOrElse`) and `Double` (value in the option).